# regular expression search a number from string

Tags: mysql, regex, numeric

this question maybe very simple for you. i'm using mysql regexp statment.

myQuery is

```
select * from contents where categories regexp '{myPattern}';
```

categories field area `54,25,99,4,2`... etc string.

my question how can i find only number of '4' from categories field.

sorry for my english.
help me please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`… WHERE FIND_IN_SET('4', categories) > 0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

better yet to normalize your db scheme with categories in their own table and then join these tables together m:n

Comment: Thank you knitll, well when I search only for 4 and 2 how is it?

Comment: what do you mean? `FIND_IN_SET('4', categories) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET('2', categories) > 0` to find both categories at the same time, use `OR` to find any category

Comment: great. but my query 4,2,54 etc. i m using for every number FIND_IN_SET('X', categories) ? is there simple other way?

Comment: I'm not following you. If you want to check for 42 categories at the same time, you have to put 42 checks into your query. How else would you expect it to work?

Answer (score 1):

The way to match "any cvs string containing '4' as a value in the string" is:

```
mycolumn regexp '[[:<:]]4[[:>:]]'
```

In mysql regex, `[[:<:]]` means "start of word" and `[[:>:]]` means "end of word".

Comment: yes - I checked after posting, and there Is a way. amended to show it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
where categories RLIKE '(^|,)4($|,)';
```

This will match when `categories` contains `4`, followed by a `,` or nothing, and precedeed by `,` or nothing.

Comment: knittl's solution looks better ;)